# Variable names that change in a loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to change old values to new values via loop.
I've tried to do it in this way:

```
old_one = 1
old_two = 2
old_three = 3

ten = 10

num_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']

for num in num_list:
    exec(f'new_{num}' + " = f'old_{num}' * ten ")

for num in num_list:
    print(f'new_{num}')
```

Expected result:

```
10
20
30
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `num_list = [one, two, three]` will be undefined as python will interpret those as variables that have not been assigned yet.

Comment: `num_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
old_one = 1
old_two = 2
old_three = 3

ten = 10

num_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']

for num in num_list:
    exec(f'new_{num} = old_{num} * ten')

for num in num_list:
    eval(f'print(new_{num})')
```

Outputs:

```
10
20
30
```

Comment: Ya beat me to it

Comment: Hah, me too. Just deleted my answer :)